# Find another method of solving the shaded area.

Tags: geometry, circles, area, quadrilateral

The diagram shows a square of side length $10\;\rm cm$. A quarter circle, of radius $10\;\rm cm$, is drawn from each vertex of the square. Find the exact area of the shaded region.

[image: Diagram]

---

And This is my answer.

> [image]

The answer is right, but I am searching for other ways.
Thanks.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Pretty clean solution. +1.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Use MathJax to type the math in your questions. This will increase your chances of getting help in this forum.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Area of intersection between 4 circles centered at the vertices of a square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/595634/area-of-intersection-between-4-circles-centered-at-the-vertices-of-a-square). See also [How calculate the shaded area in this picture?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/977998/how-calculate-the-shaded-area-in-this-picture), [How to find the area shared by 4 quadrants inside a square?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1825417/how-to-find-the-area-shared-by-4-quadrants-inside-a-square).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Area of closed figure contains square $EFGH$ and 4 segments congruent to $EF$

Area of segment can be found as difference of sector and triangle:
$$S_{seg}=\frac12 AF^2 \frac{\pi}{6}-\frac12 AF^2 \sin \frac{\pi}{6}=\frac{\pi-3}{12}AF^2$$

Square side can be found in many ways, for example with cosine rule
$$AB^2=AG^2+BG^2-2AG\cdot BG\cos \frac{5\pi}{6}=(2+\sqrt{3})AG^2$$
$$FG^2=\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{3}}AB^2=(2-\sqrt{3})AF^2$$

$$S=4S_{seg}+FG^2=\frac{\pi-3}{3}AF^2+(2-\sqrt{3})AF^2=\left(1-\sqrt{3}+\frac{\pi}{3}\right)AF^2$$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Consider circle center on D it intesect circl center on C at point G. The area under first circle and  axis can be fd as follows:

Equation of corcle :

$x^2+(y-10))^2=10^2$

Or:

$y=10-\sqrt{100-x^2}$

If $y=\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$ then:

$S=\int\sqrt{a^2-x^2}dx=\frac x2\sqrt{a^2-x^2}+\frac {a^2}2 \sin^{-1}\frac xa$

$$S=\int^{5}_0(10-\sqrt{100-x^2})dx$$

WE finally get:

$S_{AGI}=50\big(1-\frac{\sqrt 3}4-\frac{\pi}6\big)$

The  area between this circle lines AB and BC which include S is:

$$S_1=10^2-\frac 14 10^2\pi=100(1-\frac {\pi}4)$$

And the area of required region is:

$$S_2=10^2-[4\times 100(1-\frac{\pi}4)-8\times 50(1-\frac{\sqrt3}4-\frac{\pi}6)]=100\big(1-\sqrt 3+\frac {\pi}3\big)$$